# Adding marks to seek on Youtube scrubber/progress bar

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can i add marks on the scrubber to highlight like it does when a advertisement is gonna pop up(yellow mark).

Is it something we can create using youtube's API ?

[image]

Here is an example image. The red marks are what i want to add on the scrubber

Comment: Have you found anything ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported by the API. Ads appear randomly and there's no way you can add such markers in the existing Youtube bar.

Comment: Thanks for reply. any work around on how to achieve this on a custom input type of range ? marking with colors on the range input and not above it ..